# Prove that $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is solvable for all primes p

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am trying to prove that the congruence $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is solvable for all primes p. I proved it using primitive root, but my professor in number theory told me that it can be more directly done using the hasse-weil theorem in the theory of elliptic curves, but i cant do it. Would someone kindly show me how to make use of the hasse-weil theorem, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [possibly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/178880/32441)

Comment: You did consider $x=y=z=0$ I presume?

Comment: @WimC, no, this is nontrivial solutions. Famous example of Selmer on failure of Hasse-Minkowski once we leave quadratic forms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=cJ5u1yVm0HAC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=selmer+hasse-minkowski&source=bl&ots=bJGe9YvBgV&sig=oHNk2ytdDCrr1OKghQ6bv898JRY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8ut_Uo7wJ-O8iwLB3oDoDA&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=selmer%20hasse-minkowski&f=false

Comment: apparently in this: http://books.google.com/books?id=zgqUAuEJNJ4C&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=cassels+%22lectures+on+elliptic+curves%22+selmer&source=bl&ots=eletqdbRuB&sig=8kCUxmOg3SOdQVdsjVYB_4jDljk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cPB_Uv7JE6ewjAKN9YCwDw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=cassels%20%22lectures%20on%20elliptic%20curves%22%20selmer&f=false

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in $4$ steps:

1. Prove it directly for $p=2,3$, i.e., find a non-trivial solution modulo $2$ and one modulo $3$.
2. Prove that $C: 3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$ is a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p>3$ is a prime.
3. Show the following: if $C:F(x,y,z)=0$ is a non-singular curve given by a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d\geq 1$, then the genus of $C$ is given by $(d-1)(d-2)/2$. In particular, in our case, $g=1$. (This is Exercise 2.7 in Chapter 2 of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", for instance.)
4. Use the [Hasse-Weil bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves#Hasse-Weil_Bound).

**Note**: you cannot use the fact that $C/\mathbb{F}_p$ is an elliptic curve before you find a $\mathbb{F}_p$-rational point on $C$!