# Solving Diophantine equations using modular arithemtic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

One common way of showing that a Diophantine equation has no solution is to show that it doesn't have solutions modulo some integer $n$.

Such solutions often strike me as being very ad-hoc hence the following two questions:

1. Given an equation is there an algorithm that discovers if the equation isn't soluble modulo some integer $n$ and computes $n$?
2. If the above can't be done, are there at least some known general conditions an equation needs to satisfy in order to be soluble modulo every integer $n$?

Answer (score 2):

I fear that the negative result of Hilbert's 10th problem is likely to mean that approaches are always going to be a bit ad hoc.

[Hilbert's 10th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) was basically asking for an algorithm for solving (or showing unsolvability) of Diophantine equations.

A combination of [Matiyasevich's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matiyasevich%27s_theorem#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem) and results by others showed that there can be no such algorithm in general, unfortunately - or maybe fortunately, as this sort of situation does allow individual ingenuity scope to blossom.

Also worth bearing in mind is the fact that some Diophantine equations have solutions $\pmod{n}$ for all possible $n$, but still have no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$, as for example $(x^2 -2) (x^2 - 17) (x^2 - 34) = 0,$ mentioned [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178922/32441) by Will Jagy.